# The load resistance in a MOSFET current mirror vs CMOS

Tags: cmos, current-mirror, small-signal

In class I have learned that in a MOS current mirror like the one below, we can say that the load seen by M1 is equal to *r_o* of M2. This makes sense to me since I have drawn the small signal model and the calculations add up.

[image]

When we compare it to the CMOS inverter like this next diagram, we cannot say that the PMOS is equal to only a resistance since there is *v_gs* applied, that comes from *v_in* on both MOS. This also makes sense.

[image]

After understanding this when I look at the current mirror again, the fact that M2 is equivalent to only a resistance is somewhat strange. Since there is *v_sg2* applied much like in the CMOS example. So it looks like a mismatch of principle, it seems has though we are using double standards.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We can say that the load seen by M1 is equal to r_o of M2

Realize that that ignores the fact that M1 itself also has an output impedance \$r_o\$.

> the fact that M2 is equivalent to only a resistance is somewhat strange

You need to make a distinction between:

DC (where M2 behaves as a **current source**) and

AC (or "small signal") where M2 behaves as a resistance of \$r_o\$.

So in a "first order simplification", the drain of M2 behaves as a DC current source to \$V_{DD}\$ with a parallel resistance of \$r_{o,M2}\$.

So it is not "double standards" but a simplified model of the circuit depending on what behavior we want to look at.

Comment: I see... But when we look at the PMOS in the CMOS, from the prespective of NMOS  we have to take into the output resistance of the PMOS but also the signal that it receices *v_sg2*. At least that' what my teacher told me. And not only the resistance this is what sounds like a double standard.

Comment: I think i got it. In the CMOS we take into account th *v_sg2* because it's an AC signal in spite of *V_GS2* in the current mirror. Since the excitation voltage is of AC nature unlike the *VDD*.